# Translation of "will_paginate" doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, locale, will-paginate

The basic scheme:

```
= will_paginate @products, :previous_label => t("previous_label"), :next_label => t("next_label")
```

**de.yml**

```
  will_paginate:
    page_gap: "&hellip;"
    previous_label: "word for back"
    next_label: "word for next"
```

**en.yml**
    en:
      will_paginate:
        page_gap: "…"
        previous_label: "previous"
        next_label: "next"

But in the output are still the labels called `Previous Label` and `Next Label`.
What is still wrong? Also, I thought I didn't restart the server... but after restart still the same labels, not my translations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can grab YAML files translated in various languages for will_paginate here : https://github.com/tigrish/will-paginate-i18n.

In your example, you're overriding the :previous_label and the :next_label, but you're not scoping it to 'will_paginate'.

Either remove the overrides completely and customise the labels in your translation file :

```
will_paginate @products
```

or scope the `.t` calls correctly :

```
will_paginate @products,
  :previous_label => t("will_paginate.previous_label"),
  :next_label     => t("will_paginate.next_label")
```

Comment: It is better to use the gem 'will-paginate-i18n'

Answer (score 4):

you can then change the text of the pagination links by adding the following to `config/locales/will_paginate.en.yml:`

```
en:
  will_paginate:
    page_gap: "&hellip;"
    previous_label: "previous"
    next_label: "next"
```

And add following in `application.rb`

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
```